# A method that searches for entities, a certain property of which matches a given criteria in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, entity-framework, search

Okay, I'm not sure whether the title of the question is clear enough, but I couldn't think of a simpler explanation in one sentence.

I'm making a search page for a ASP.NET web application. I want to allow the users to search using different filters.

I came up with a method that filters the Publications (these are the entities that the user will retrieve) based on the type of Categories that the user has chosen.

```
List<Publication> publications =
            (from p in GetPublications()
             where categories.Contains((int)p.CategoryId)
             select p).ToList();
```

The above linq query is equivalent to the following sql one:

```
select * from Publication p where p.CategoryId in (@chosenCategoryIds)
```

Everything works perfect but the problem is that I want to allow the user to choose from more filters, for example, not only categories, but users, tags, titles and etc.

So, if I want this, I should make a lot of conditional statements checking whether the user has provided given filters or not, something like:

```
if (categories != null)
{
    var publications = (from p in GetPublications()
                       where categories.Contains((int)p.CategoryId)
                       select p).ToList();

    if (users != null)
    {
        publications = (from p in publications 
                       where users.Contains((int)p.UserId)
                       select p).ToList();
    }
}
else 
{
// Handle other situations..
}
```

So, it turns out that I'm doing basically one and the same thing for different filters. My question is whether somebody knows or can think of a better way to achieve this? If not, let's take a look at the following method:

```
public List<InterpretumDAL.Publication> FilterPublications(List<InterpretumDAL.Publication> oldList, int[] values)
{
    List<InterpretumDAL.Publication> newList =
        (from p in oldList
         where values.Contains((int)p.CategoryId)
         select p).ToList();

    return newList;
}
```

What I try to achieve with the method above is to filter a given list by a given array of values. The thing is that I don't know how to tell the method which property to compare, so I can call it something like this:

```
newList = FilterPublications(publications, categories, CATEGORY_PROPERTY_OF_PUBLICATION);
newList = FilterPublications(publications, users, USER_PROPERTY_OF_PUBLICATION);
newList = FilterPublications(publications, tags, TAG_PROPERTY_OF_PUBLICATION);
```

**Edit:**
According to LiquidPony's answer I did it this way:

```
var publications = (from p in GetPublications()
                    where (
                    (categories == null || categories.Length == 0 || (p.CategoryId.HasValue && categories.Contains((int)p.CategoryId)))
                    && (users == null || users.Length == 0 || users.Contains(p.UserId))
                    && (tags == null || tags.Length == 0 || tags.Contains(p.TagId))
                    )
                    select p).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to do something like this:

```
var query = from p in GetPublications()
            where (
                  (categories == null || categories.Contains((int)p.CategoryId))
                  && (users == null || users.Contains((int)p.UserId))
                  && (tags == null || tags.Contains((int)p.TagId))
            ) select p;
```

That would work if you want to match all criteria.  You can switch the `&&` to `||` if you want to return entities which only match one criteria.

Comment: I think it is more efficient to use a ternary operator, rather than using the OR. OR's are incredibly inefficient in SQL for larger datasets.

Comment: When I have to compare whether categories == null and etc. in the where clause of the LINQ query, I get an exception, stating: "Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Int32[]'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported.".

Comment: True, I just assumed it was `IQueryable` due to Entity Framework being mentioned :D

Comment: Julian - what is the method signature of `GetPublications()`?  If it's returning `IQueryable<Publication>`, you will need to call `.ToList()` on the returned value in order to use the query I suggested.

Comment: Julian - also, what are `categories` and `users` and `tags`?  Are they `List<int>`?

Answer (score 2):

Taking LiquidPony's answer, I think it would be better to do it like this by using ternary operators.

```
var query = from p in GetPublications()
        where (
              (categories != null ? categories.Contains((int)p.CategoryId) : true)
              && (users != null ? users.Contains((int)p.UserId) : true)
              && (tags != null ? tags.Contains((int)p.TagId) : true)
        ) select p;
```

If one of the variables isn't provided, that statement will simply evaluate to true and not be included in the SQL evaluation (as far as I know).

You want to avoid using OR's unless absolutely necessary. They are quite inefficient in SQL, and you can usually always find an alternative to get what you want without using them.

Comment: The `||` in `categories == null || categories.Contains(...)` won't be executed as SQL, though.  I think use of the ternary operator in this case is harder to read and generates a much more complex SQL query (though an execution plan shows the cost to be identical).  If `categories == null` is true, the `||` will short-circuit.

Comment: I just tried a sample query with both ternary and `||` queries, it appears that you are correct in that it evaluates to a more complex query, but the execution cost/time is negligible. Though I guess the more complex SQL may be of concern when you have to transmit it to the server.

Comment: I don't know that the complexity of the SQL query actually matters except for tracing/debugging purposes.  The important point for me is that, except in specific cases, a straight `||` comparison is easier to read than the ternary.